# Angular - Iterate and concatenate a variable to a string to call function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a table that iterate on a json file and to display the price of a json file and which allows me to call function which also iterate, ie (ngModelChange)="calcul0()" for the 1st line, (ngModelChange)="calcul1()" for the 2nd line.

But, as it's "dumb" to create 10 times this line, I wanted to concatenate the name of the function and the variable I iterate on.
I tried:

```
<tr *ngFor='let day of year(10) ;let i= index'>
    <td>{{products[i].date}}</td>
    <td>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price" + i (ngModelChange)="calcul" + [i] + "()"
            placeholder="Price"
            value="{{products[i].price | currency :'EUR':'symbol':'1.2-2'}}"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I come more from a PHP background so obviously I tried something like the echo line of PHP but didn't succeed. I tried to implement a script directly on the html file and to make a "document.write(i)" but it didn't work out.

Is it possible to iterate and concatenate?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this would be to just create an array of product prices (or use the variable that you already have) and to make your `calcul` function accept a parameter for the product you are changing.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="products[i].price" (ngModelChange)="calcul(products[i])"
            placeholder="Price"
            value="{{products[i].price | currency :'EUR':'symbol':'1.2-2'}}"/>
```

Comment: Can a ngModel be based on a incremented variable too? Because for this example, the name wasn't clear but it's not based on the products[i].price but on a variable I incremented like price1, price2 ... and declared on my ts file.

Comment: You shouldn't have a bunch of price variables. You should have a single price array and then use `price[i]`

Comment: I never used it. I tried to create a variable price price = [0,1,2,3,...] but I cannot increment on it. I really need to work on it